# Disable "you are about to open" pop up

Tags: 2010, document

Everytime I open a document in SharePoint it asks:

You are about to open
Name: xxxxxx
From: xxxxxxx

How would you like to open this file?
Read Only
Edit

How do I disable this, so it opens directly into read only?

Comment: any solution found ?

Comment: Solution of move sites to 'trusted sites' Section solve problem for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no simple way of doing that - Browser File Handling won't help you, because it is useful only when you want to prevent "Save document to disk" behavior.

Try to locate docicon.xml file and search there for one of your file extensions you want to open, and try to add there attribute OpenControl="". If that won't help, you will need to do some more customizations in aspx files probably with the DispEx method.

Comment: I had to add `OpenApp=""` as well. so, my mapping looked like this eventually: `<Mapping Key="myextention" Value="MyIcon.png" OpenControl="" OpenApp="" />`

Answer (score 2):

Check out the ***Browser File Handling*** section of this article.  I think you'll want to set it to *Permissive* to automatically open the documents.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262107.aspx

Comment: didn't worked for me :-(

Answer (score 1):

Add it to your trusted sites in IE and it will go away...

Comment: I have tried all the above - adding 'OpenControl=""' to the docicon.xml, BrowserFilehandling set to permissive, adding it to the trusted sites It still happens